# How to get magento root file path in controller in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, directory, paths

How to get magento root file path in controller in Magento 2 ?

Like if my magento root file path is /var/www/html/magento in Controller file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get like this one :

```
protected $_dir;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir) 
{
    $this->_dir = $dir;
}

public yourfunction()
{
   $this->_dir->getRoot(); // Output: /var/www/html/magento
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response it works @Dhiren